# Make clang-format do not pack list initialization

Tags: c++, clang-format

I am trying to configure clang-format.
Currently my `.clang-format` file looks like:

```
Language: Cpp

IndentWidth: 4
```

I have unformatted map declaration:

```
  map<string, unsigned> register_dictionary = {
    {"r0", 0},
    {"r1", 1},
    {"r2", 2},
    {"r3", 3},
    {"r4", 4},
    {"r5", 5},
    {"r6", 6} ,
    {"r7", 7},
    {"r8", 8},
    {"r9", 9},
    {"r10", 10},
    {"r11", 11},
    {"r12", 12},
    {"r13", 13},
    {"r14", 14},
    {"r15", 15},
  };
```

I want my formatter just to format indentations, but instead it does following:

```
    map<string, unsigned> register_dictionary = {
        {"r0", 0},   {"r1", 1},   {"r2", 2},   {"r3", 3},
        {"r4", 4},   {"r5", 5},   {"r6", 6},   {"r7", 7},
        {"r8", 8},   {"r9", 9},   {"r10", 10}, {"r11", 11},
        {"r12", 12}, {"r13", 13}, {"r14", 14}, {"r15", 15},
    };
```

But I don't want such kind of packing.
How can I avoid packing?

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#allowallargumentsonnextline ? But it will force this configuration to every initialization that doesn't fit in one line.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, didn't work((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made following and it worked:

```
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
```